# Does the shadow copy the form of the living doll or is the living doll made in the form of the shadow?

Tags: shadows-house

This is a question I had while watching *Shadows House*. In particular, I became a bit puzzled after some stuff was explained around the middle of the first season. This information was as follows:

> The beginning stage of a shadow is a small fairy creature called a morph. They are shown the human form (the living dolls) and this leads to them copying it.

> What leads to my confusion is as to whether they copy the human form they see exactly, or make their own original copy of "a human". There's an unanswered question of the time frame for these things, both for the living dolls and the shadows. If the shadows copy their living doll's form at this point, then what were the living dolls doing up until they met their master? It seemed like on Emiliko's first day, she was introduced to Kate. Thus, my confusion.

I want to know who is copying whom, but I hesitate asking this question, because I might be heading into spoiler territory, as the whole situation may be elaborated upon further down the line. On the other hand, I might just be making strange assumptions and raising invalid questions, so I might be supposed to know at this point whether the shadow or the living doll comes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is indeed a spoiler, and one which a viewer should be able to figure out by the end of the first season, given the revelations there.

If you just want the answer:

> It is the shadows who copy the form of the living dolls.

And I know this is the answer because (warning, this is a major spoiler!):

> The living dolls are actually not living dolls. They are brainwashed human children. Thus, it is impossible for them to be created in the form of the shadow, and it must be the case that the shadow copies their form. The brainwashed humans can have their memories erased as well, so this could go a long way towards explaining any time incongruities.